# How to pass a singleton to another class in qt

Tags: c++, qt

In the `main.cpp`i'm creating a singleton type of a class to use it in qml with the following function:

`qmlRegisterSingletonType<DataloopWrapper>("com.xpto.connector", 1, 0, "DataloopWrapper",&DataloopWrapper::qmlInstance);`

a bit down on the `main.cpp` i call a function of another object where i want to call a function from that `singleton`

maybe something like this `qmlTranslator.loadLanguage(lang, DataloopWrapper::qmlInstance);` is possible?

I'm declaring `QmlTranslator`class the following way:

```
#ifndef QMLTRANSLATOR_H
#define QMLTRANSLATOR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QGuiApplication>

class QmlTranslator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QmlTranslator(QQmlEngine *engine, QGuiApplication *app);
    Q_INVOKABLE void selectLanguage(QString language);
    void InstallTranslator();
    void loadLanguage(QString language, QObject*(QQmlEngine*,QJSEngine*) objDataloop);
    virtual ~QmlTranslator();
signals:
    void languageChanged();

private:
    QTranslator *_translator;
    QQmlEngine *_engine;
    QGuiApplication *_app;
};


#endif // QMLTRANSLATOR_H
```

I'm not finding a way to pass `DataloopWrapper::qmlInstance`as argument. At least it gives error in `void loadLanguage(QString language, QObject*(QQmlEngine*,QJSEngine*) objDataloop);`on the qmlTranslator definition.

From a public: Members of `DataloopWrapper`i have the defenition of `qmlInstance`, it's this:

```
class DataloopWrapper : public QObject, public something::DataloopCBHandler,
                        public something::DataloopTransferCBHandler
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataloopWrapper(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~DataloopWrapper();
    static QObject *qmlInstance(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(engine);
        Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine);

        return new DataloopWrapper;
    }
```

Comment: How is `qmlTranslator.loadLanguage` declared? What kind of arguments does it accept? Does it take an `DataloopWrapper::qmlInstance` object by reference? A pointer to such an object? By value?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've added what i'm trying to do in ```QmlTranslator```class, but it is not possible to pass a ```QObject*(QQmlEngine*,QJSEngine*) ```as argument or at least i'm not finding a way to do it.

Comment: That almost looks like you're declaring a pointer to a (non-member) function. What are you really supposed to pass? What is `DataloopWrapper::qmlInstance`?

Comment: @someprogrammerdude i'ts a ```QObject```

Comment: A *pointer* to a `QObject` or just a plain `QObject`? If it's a pointer, then it's really no different from any other pointer argument you should already know about. If it's an instance (a value) then either use the address-of operator to pass a pointer, or have the function take a reference to the object. Again no different from what you should (hopefully) already know about pointer or reference arguments.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude from what i see it is defined as a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

`DataloopWrapper::qmlInstance` is a *function*, that you need to *call* in order to get a pointer to a `QObject`.

For for any function you want to pass this object, you need to make it accept a pointer to a `QObject` (type `QObject*`), and don't forget to *call* `DataloopWrapper::qmlInstance`.

---

Translated into code:

```
class QmlTranslator : public QObject
{
    ...
    void loadLanguage(QString language, QObject* objDataloop);
    ...
};

...

qmlTranslator.loadLanguage(lang, DataloopWrapper::qmlInstance(aQMLEngineObjectPointer, aQJSEnginePointer));
```